# Object doesn't suport this property or method in IE8 when checking if checkbox is checked after setting attr('checked');

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, checked

This is behavior is kind of strange.

In IE8 when I use $('something').is(':checked') to check if a checkbox is checked after setting it using $('something').attr('checked', true). I get an error when I run the script a **second** time.

I created a jsfiddle and the same issue occurs there.

After the following page loads, click run again. I get Object doesn't support this property or method in IE8

http://jsfiddle.net/Dxvmg/6/

Any ideas?

I am using jquery 1.6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've found a bug in jsfiddle.  Seemed to work fine in a stand-alone web page.

Comment: I guess this is precisely my problem. The first run seems to be fine for me...but the second run (not in jsfiddle) gives that exact same error.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  I guess you always have to consider the test environment when debugging something.